# Suppose $X$ follows normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. If $\sigma \rightarrow 0$, can we get $\mathbb{E}(f(x)) \rightarrow f(\mu)$?

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X$ follows normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. If $\sigma \rightarrow 0$, can we get $\mathbb{E}(f(x)) \rightarrow f(\mu)$ for any function $f$? I think so intuitively, but how can we prove it? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can prove it by showing that $\lim_{\sigma\to 0}p_X(x)\to \delta(x)$ where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: "Any function" seems a little broad.

Comment: Try a function $f(x)$ that increases very quickly with $x$, relative to the $e^{-x^2}$ decay of the Gaussian PDF.

Comment: Try $f(\mu) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1000$ for $x \neq \mu$.